# Enable Client to Talk to Server using the NetMQ "Realiable Pub/Sub" Pattern

Tags: c#, zeromq, netmq

I have a v4.0.0.1 implementation of Somdron's "Reliable Pub-Sub" pattern for communication between two parts of a new application. This application will have a "Server" (the engine that does all the heavy calculations) and "Clients" that will send requests and get information on progress back from the server.

The problem I have with my current version of "Reliable Pub-Sub" is that I don't seem to have a proper way for sending requests to the sever from the client. Let me start by showing you the code:

**SERVER:**

```
using NetMQ;
using NetMQ.Sockets;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo.Messaging.Server
{
    public class ZeroMqMessageServer : IDisposable
    {
        private const string WELCOME_MESSAGE = "WM";
        private const string HEARTBEAT_MESSAGE = "HB";
        private const string PUBLISH_MESSAGE_TOPIC = "PUB";
        private readonly TimeSpan HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

        private NetMQActor actor;
        private NetMQTimer heartbeatTimer;
        private XPublisherSocket publisher;
        private NetMQPoller poller;

        public ZeroMqMessageServer(string address)
        {
            Address = address;
            actor = NetMQActor.Create(Start);
        }

        private void Start(PairSocket shim)
        {
            using (publisher = new XPublisherSocket())
            {
                publisher.SetWelcomeMessage(WELCOME_MESSAGE);
                publisher.Bind(Address);

                //publisher.ReceiveReady -= DropPublisherSubscriptions;
                publisher.ReceiveReady += DropPublisherSubscriptions;

                heartbeatTimer = new NetMQTimer(HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL);
                heartbeatTimer.Elapsed += OnHeartbeatTimeElapsed;

                shim.ReceiveReady += OnShimReceiveReady;
                shim.SignalOK(); // Let the actor know we are ready to work. 

                poller = new NetMQPoller() { publisher, shim, heartbeatTimer };
                poller.Run();
            }
        }

        private void DropPublisherSubscriptions(object sender, NetMQSocketEventArgs e)
        {
            publisher.SkipMultipartMessage();
        }

        private void OnHeartbeatTimeElapsed(object sender, NetMQTimerEventArgs e)
        {
            publisher.SendFrame(HEARTBEAT_MESSAGE);
        }

        private void OnShimReceiveReady(object sender, NetMQSocketEventArgs e)
        {
            var socket = e.Socket;
            string command = socket.ReceiveFrameString();

            if (command == PUBLISH_MESSAGE_TOPIC)
            {
                // Forward the message to the publisher. 
                NetMQMessage message = socket.ReceiveMultipartMessage();
                publisher.SendMultipartMessage(message);
            }
            else if (command == NetMQActor.EndShimMessage)
            {
                // Dispose command received, stop the poller. 
                poller.Stop();
            }
        }

        public void PublishMessage(NetMQMessage message)
        {
            // We can use actor like NetMQSocket and publish messages.
            actor.SendMoreFrame(PUBLISH_MESSAGE_TOPIC)
                 .SendMultipartMessage(message);
        }

        public string Address { get; private set; }

        private bool disposedValue = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    actor?.Dispose();
                    publisher?.Dispose();
                    poller?.Dispose();
                }
                disposedValue = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**CLIENT:**

```
using NetMQ;
using NetMQ.Sockets;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Messaging.Helpers;

namespace Demo.Messaging.Client
{
    public class ZeroMqMessageClient : IDisposable
    {
        private string SUBSCRIBE_COMMAND = "S";
        private const string WELCOME_MESSAGE = "WM";
        private const string HEARTBEAT_MESSAGE = "HB";
        private const string PUBLISH_MESSAGE_TOPIC = "PUB";

        private readonly TimeSpan TIMEOUT = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        private readonly TimeSpan RECONNECTION_PERIOD = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

        private readonly string[] addressCollection;
        private List<string> subscriptions = new List<string>();

        private NetMQTimer timeoutTimer;
        private NetMQTimer reconnectionTimer;

        private NetMQActor actor;
        private SubscriberSocket subscriber;
        private PairSocket shim;
        private NetMQPoller poller;

        public ZeroMqMessageClient(params string[] addresses)
        {
            addressCollection = addresses;
            actor = NetMQActor.Create(Start);
        }

        private void Start(PairSocket shim)
        {
            this.shim = shim;
            shim.ReceiveReady += OnShimReceiveReady;

            timeoutTimer = new NetMQTimer(TIMEOUT);
            timeoutTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeoutTimerElapsed;

            reconnectionTimer = new NetMQTimer(RECONNECTION_PERIOD);
            reconnectionTimer.Elapsed += OnReconnectionTimerElapsed;

            poller = new NetMQPoller() { shim, timeoutTimer, reconnectionTimer };
            shim.SignalOK();
            Connect();

            poller.Run();
            if (subscriber != null)
                subscriber.Dispose();
        }

        private void Connect()
        {
            using (NetMQPoller tmpPoller = new NetMQPoller())
            {
                List<SubscriberSocket> socketCollection = new List<SubscriberSocket>();
                SubscriberSocket connectedSocket = null;

                EventHandler<NetMQSocketEventArgs> messageHandler = (s, e) =>
                {
                    connectedSocket = (SubscriberSocket)e.Socket;
                    tmpPoller.Stop();
                };

                // We cancel the poller without setting the connected socket.
                NetMQTimer tmpTimeoutTimer = new NetMQTimer(TIMEOUT);
                tmpTimeoutTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) => tmpPoller.Stop();
                tmpPoller.Add(tmpTimeoutTimer);

                // Attempt to subscribe to the supplied list of addresses.
                foreach (var address in addressCollection)
                {
                    SubscriberSocket socket = new SubscriberSocket();
                    socketCollection.Add(socket);

                    //socket.ReceiveReady -= messageHandler;
                    socket.ReceiveReady += messageHandler;
                    tmpPoller.Add(socket);

                    // Subscribe to welcome messages.
                    socket.Subscribe(WELCOME_MESSAGE);
                    socket.Connect(address);
                }
                tmpPoller.Run(); // Block and wait for connection. 

                // We should have an active socket/conection. 
                if (connectedSocket != null)
                {
                    // Remove the connected socket from the collection.
                    socketCollection.Remove(connectedSocket);
                    ZeroMqHelpers.CloseConnectionsImmediately(socketCollection);

                    // Set the active socket.
                    subscriber = connectedSocket;
                    //subscriber.SkipMultipartMessage(); // This skips the welcome message.

                    // Subscribe to subscriptions.
                    subscriber.Subscribe(HEARTBEAT_MESSAGE);
                    foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
                        subscriber.Subscribe(subscription);

                    // Remove start-up handler, now handle messages properly. 
                    subscriber.ReceiveReady -= messageHandler;
                    subscriber.ReceiveReady += OnSubscriberReceiveReady;
                    poller.Add(subscriber);

                    // Reset timers.
                    timeoutTimer.Enable = true;
                    reconnectionTimer.Enable = false;
                }
                else // We need to attempt re-connection.
                {
                    // Close all existing connections. 
                    ZeroMqHelpers.CloseConnectionsImmediately(socketCollection);
                    timeoutTimer.Enable = false;
                    reconnectionTimer.Enable = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnShimReceiveReady(object sender, NetMQSocketEventArgs e)
        {
            string command = e.Socket.ReceiveFrameString();

            if (command == NetMQActor.EndShimMessage)
            {
                poller.Stop();
            }
            else if (command == SUBSCRIBE_COMMAND)
            {
                string topic = e.Socket.ReceiveFrameString();
                subscriptions.Add(topic);
                if (subscriber != null)
                    subscriber.Subscribe(topic);
            }
        }

        private void OnTimeoutTimerElapsed(object sender, NetMQTimerEventArgs e)
        {
            if (subscriber != null)
            {
                poller.Remove(subscriber);
                subscriber.Dispose();
                subscriber = null;
                Connect();
            }
        }

        private void OnReconnectionTimerElapsed(object sender, NetMQTimerEventArgs e)
        {
            // We re-attempt connection. 
            Connect();
        }

        private void OnSubscriberReceiveReady(object sender, NetMQSocketEventArgs e)
        {
            // Here we just forwward the message on to the actor. 
            var message = subscriber.ReceiveMultipartMessage();
            string topic = message[0].ConvertToString();

            // Let us see what is in the message.
            if (message.Count() > 1)
            {
                string content = message[1].ConvertToString();
                Console.WriteLine($"ZMQ_ALT - {topic}:: {content}");
            }

            if (topic == WELCOME_MESSAGE)
            {
                // Disconnection has occurred we might want to restore state from a snapshot. 
            }
            else if (topic == HEARTBEAT_MESSAGE)
            {
                // We got a heartbeat, lets postponed the timer.
                timeoutTimer.Enable = false;
                timeoutTimer.Enable = true;
            }
            else
            {
                shim.SendMultipartMessage(message);
            }
        }

        public void Subscribe(string topic)
        {
            actor.SendMoreFrame(SUBSCRIBE_COMMAND).SendFrame(topic);
        }

        public NetMQMessage ReceiveMessage()
        {
            return actor.ReceiveMultipartMessage();
        }

        public void PublishMessage(NetMQMessage message)
        {
            actor.SendMoreFrame(PUBLISH_MESSAGE_TOPIC)
                 .SendMultipartMessage(message);
        }

        private bool disposedValue = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    actor?.Dispose();
                    subscriber?.Dispose();
                    shim?.Dispose();
                    poller?.Dispose();
                }
                disposedValue = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I can send messages from the server to the client which is awesome and the client using the following code from the main method in two separate console applications

**Program.cs for SERVER:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ZeroMqMessageServer server = new ZeroMqMessageServer("tcp://127.0.0.1:6669"))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                NetMQMessage message = new NetMQMessage();
                message.Append("A");
                message.Append(new Random().Next().ToString());

                server.PublishMessage(message);
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs for CLIENT:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (ZeroMqMessageClient client = new ZeroMqMessageClient("tcp://127.0.0.1:6669"))
            {
                client.Subscribe(String.Empty);
                while (true) { }
            }
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The client correctly auto-detects dropped connections and reconnects, fantastic little pattern.

However, this pattern out-of-the-box does not allow the client to send messages to the server. So in the client I have added the following code

```
public void PublishMessage(NetMQMessage message)
{
    actor.SendMoreFrame(PUBLISH_MESSAGE_TOPIC)
          .SendMultipartMessage(message);
}
```

and in the client I have changed the `publisher.ReceiveReady += DropPublisherSubscriptions;` event handler to

```
    private void DropPublisherSubscriptions(object sender, NetMQSocketEventArgs e)
    {
        var message = e.Socket.ReceiveMultipartMessage();
        string topic = message[0].ConvertToString();
        Console.WriteLine($"TOPIC = {topic}");

        // Let us see what is in the message.
        if (message.Count() > 1)
        {
            string content = message[1].ConvertToString();
            Console.WriteLine($"TEST RECIEVE FROM CLIENT - {topic}:: {content}");
        }

        publisher.SkipMultipartMessage();
    }
```

but this does not seem to handle my messages. It receives the heartbeats and welcome messages, but I am not doing this right.

*How can I enable/facilitate the client to talk to the server without breaking what I have already?*

Thanks for your time.

Comment: While not really on topic... I did a lot of such client server comm in my time (with other mostly self written technologies) and this code here appears to be very lengthy compared to what I expected to see. Probably I would look for alternatives if you run into show stoppers.

Comment: I am thinking I might need to use a new pattern for this, like Lazy Pirate pattern.

Comment: I have established that this is probably the wrong pattern. I really want the Asynchronous client/server in C# shown in [Figure 37 - Asynchronous Client/Server of the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-Asynchronous-Client-Server-Pattern). I will be attempting an implementation of this with heartbeat and re-connection capabilities...